# Error message: 'Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body. (arrow-body-style)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'm using "eslint-config-airbnb": "13.0.0", to keep my JavaScript clean

```
const formatedUserList = trainerOnly.map((user) => { //eslint 'Unexpected 
  return {
    ...user,
    value: user.id,
    label: user.name,
  };
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8SLb.png)

It seems like this might be an ongoing issue. Does anyone have any suggestions for an OCD developer on how to address this in the meantime? Perhaps disabling this rule or otherwise?

Comment: Welcome on SO. For next time please include code and text version of error message - this would be much easier to work with and also it will be indexed by google for others with the same issue

Answer (score 4):

Because your function is returning an object immediately, your linting rule is suggesting that you return the object *implicitly* to reduce syntax noise. That is, instead of what you're doing, use:

```
.map((user) => ({
  ...user,
  value: user.id,
  label: user.name,
}));
```

Or, of course, you could just disable the `arrow-body-style` rule if you don't think requiring a consistent style in this situation is useful for you.

You can also omit the parentheses around the parameter list if you wish:

```
.map(user => ({
```

Comment: ...also in case of just single argument it's possible to skip parenthesis around: `(user) => ` becomes `user => `; but it's up to style preferred